# How can I change the selected text when using Multiple Select jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, multi-select, jquery-ui-multiselect

I am using this cool [Multiple Select plugin](http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/docs/#multiple-select)

Please look at ["The Position"](http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/docs/#the-position) options. I would need to display either 1 text or 5 of 12 selected.

so If I only select 1 option then display that option if I select more than 1 then just state 2 of 12 are selected.

It seems that the default here is set to 4 and I need to override this.

How can I change the default value?

Here is my code

```
$(function(){                                           
   $(".multipleSelectMenuMask").multiselect({
   enableFiltering: true,
   enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
   selectedClass: null,
   nonSelectedText: "Select an option",
   includeSelectAllOption: true,
   buttonWidth: "100%",
   maxHeight: 250
   });
});
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: I just updated my question with the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the problem.

I am using bootstrap-multiselect not Multiple Select plugin

the option is

```
numberDisplayed
```

Answer (score 1):

use Bootstrap multiselect [here](http://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/)

```
$(".example-class-multiselect").multiselect({
    nonSelectedText: "Select an option",
    allSelectedText: "Selected all",
    nSelectedText  : "Selected",
    //...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at constructor http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/docs/#constructor

```
minimumCountSelected
```

Type: int

countSelected will be shown only if more than X items where selected.

By default this option is set to 3.

Comment: That did not work. it did not change anything. I also tried countSelected

Comment: Did you try something like this `$("select").multipleSelect({
            minimumCountSelected: 1,
            multiple: true
        });`

Comment: countSelected is a template for minimumCountSelected, I don't know why it doesn't works!

Answer (score 0):

Bower get not last version of plugin. Check your sources:

```
Line 245: } else if (selects.length > this.options.minumimCountSelected && this.options.countSelected) {
```

and

```
Line 443: minumimCountSelected: 3,
```

`minUmIm`

Now you can change option name to minumimCountSelected and temporary fix it in version 1.1.0.